# Remove an input from a session in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, shinyjs

I am facing the following problem: I have a shiny app where a user is going through a planning process (there is a lot of user input). When the process is complete, I'd like to implement an observeEvent which **deletes the rendered inputs from the Shiny Session**. I don't want them to reset or show the default value. But I want the user input to be deleted from the session and an error message to appear that the input cannot be found.

Is there a possibility to remove / drop a (user) input element from a session in Shiny?

**Hypothetically example**

```r
observeEvent(input$action_button, { rm(input$XYZ)})
```

**Wanted error message:**

```
Error : Problem with `mutate()` input `XYZ`. x object 'XYZ' not found
```

Comment: I would just use the respective updateInput to set it to NA: https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/update-input-demo.html

Comment: To delete the rendered inputs, you may be interested in `removeUI()`. But notice that even if you reset to default values, or remove the rendered inputs, the variable `input$XYZ` cannot be easily removed from Shiny's framework. This is documented https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2439 and https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2374. Those links offer a hack on how to do it, but there is no built in function to do it. input values are read only.

Answer (score 1):

The following example uses `removeUI()` to remove rendered input elements created on instantiation of the app or dynamically added with `insertUI()`.

Note that even after the UI is removed, the input variables, `input$new_button` or `input$user_select`, still exist. See comment above.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- basicPage(
  h4("removeUI(), insertUI()"),
  actionButton("add", "add dynamic ui"),
  actionButton("remove", "remove dynamic ui"),
  div(id = "dynamic_ui"),
  
  hr(),
  h4("removeUI() of an element loded at app instantiation"),
  actionButton("remove_select", "remove regular ui"),
  div(id = "select_ui", 
      selectInput("user_select", "select color", choices = c("A","B","C"))),
  
  hr(),
  verbatimTextOutput("text")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    insertUI(
      selector = "#dynamic_ui",
      ui = actionButton("new_button", "new button")
    )
  })
  observeEvent(input$remove, {
    removeUI(
      selector = "#new_button"
    )
  })
  observeEvent(input$remove_select, {
    removeUI(
      selector = "#select_ui"
    )
  })
  output$text <- renderPrint({
    names(input)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```